# Cloning an aurelia-cli project does not work

Tags: git, clone, aurelia

I'm trying to clone an aurelia project in a git archive to a new Win10 laptop. I have downloaded the git source code archive and installed node, npm and Aurelia-cli on the new laptop. When I run `au run` in the project root, the au-cli does not see the aurelia_project folder. Instead, it prompts me to create a new project.

> How do I tell Aurelia-cli to reuse the existing aurelia project?

Comment: I don't know about `aurelia` but did you run `npm install` and `npm link aurelia-cli`?

Comment: I did npm install aurelia-cli -g, This installs the aurelia-cli. That works. But aurelia-cli does not see the cloned aurelia project when i do au run in the project root folder.